# Need to integrate Azure key vault with Azure web app code connection string

Tags: .net, azure, .net-core, azure-sql-database, azure-keyvault

I have one website which I have posted on Azure web app and that website is connected with SQL database so we are try to setup that database connection string password directly attach with Azure key vault. We don't have any idea how can we add that function. Anyone please help me on this.

Follow my connection string with DB login code:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LoginLevel": {
      "Default": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "test",
  "connectionStrings": {
    "demoDBConnection": "Data Source = test-QA-sqldemo.public.demo.database.windows.net,3342; Initial Catalog = demo;persist security info=False; user id=sql-demo;password=test;timeout=30"
  }
}
```

So how can I retrieve the password in this connection string using Azure key vault so we can remove this SQL password and setup key vault method?

Answer (score 0):

> we are try to setup that database connection string passwordd directly catch with azure key vault

You can **store whole database connection string into azure key vault** instead of only password. Refer to the steps as below:

1.Create a azure key vault and add demoDBConnection with its value as secret in key vault.

2.Enable Managed Identity for your azure webapp.

3.Go to you key vault and click Access policies and add the webapp's service principle with Secret's `Get` permission.

4.Then in azure webapp, use the following code to get the connection string in key vault.

```
var azureServiceTokenProvider = new AzureServiceTokenProvider();
var keyVaultClient = new KeyVaultClient(new KeyVaultClient.AuthenticationCallback(azureServiceTokenProvider.KeyVaultTokenCallback));
var secret = await keyVaultClient.GetSecretAsync("KeyVaultUrl", secretName).ConfigureAwait(false);
var secretValue = secret.Value;
```

For more details, you could refer to this [article](https://jeremylindsayni.wordpress.com/2018/03/15/using-the-azure-key-vault-to-keep-secrets-out-of-your-web-apps-source-code/).

Also, you could use [Key Vault references](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-key-vault-references) for App Service like below:

```
@Microsoft.KeyVault(SecretUri=https://myvault.vault.azure.net/secrets/mysecret/ec96f02080254f109c51a1f14cdb1931)
```

Comment: how can i add merge this into the following code 
  "Logging": {
    "LoginLevel": {
      "Default": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "test",
  "connectionStrings": {
    "demoDBConnection": "Data Source = test-QA-sqldemo.public.demo.database.windows.net,3342; Initial Catalog = demo;persist security info=False; user id=sql-demo;password=test;timeout=30"
  }
}

Comment: You do not need to all the json file in key vault. As you only want to secure your connectionstring, you only need to add the connectionstring into keyvault. Follow the steps as I provided above.

Comment: how can i mearge your provided code into my conection string code. can you guide me on it......... Thanks. conection

Comment: follow the steps I provided and put the connectionstring as key vault secret.